# Database Row with Multiple JSON values - How to get a specific value

Tags: php, json

So my question of the day would be, how can i get a specific value from a single database row which has multiple JSON values using Php.

The data has been put in the Database as such:

```
a:7:{s:5:"cname";s:4:"enes";s:6:"cemail";s:22:"EnesDemirICT@gmail.com";s:8:"caddress";s:18:"Florisvosstraat 56";s:4:"ctel";s:12:"+31685035990";s:9:"ccomments";s:5:"fdfsf";s:15:"wppizza-gateway";s:3:"cod";s:12:"wppizza_hash";s:64:"34e24d48186596cae445d52c5b0650d20c8a7c215ef1fe323ca6f09b7f804a8d";}
```

So ofcourse i already have the code to get this from the database which is as following.

```
<?php 

header('content-type:application/json');

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('depits');

$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test_json`");

$rows=array();


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

How would i be able to process the data i received and get for example, only get the value of name and email. If this vague or simply not a good question please comment on it so i might better it for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json seems incorrect, http://jsonlint.com/

This is how I do it:

```
<?
$test = '{"John": {"status":"Wait"},"Jennifer":{"status":"Active"},"James": {"status":"Active", "age":56,"count":10,"progress":0.0029857,"bad":0}}';

// decode your json  into associative arrays
$decoded = json_decode($test, true);

//easy to read the array
echo "<pre>";
print_r($decoded);
echo "</pre>";

// james age

echo "Age: ". $decoded['James']['age'];
?>
```

I guess this is what you are looking for. To get all names you need a foreach loop

```
<?
$json = '{
"People": 
    [{
        "name":"peter",
        "age" :"50"
    },{
        "name":"phil",
        "age" :"25"
    },{
        "name":"mike",
        "age" :"23"
    }] 
}';

// decode your json  into associative arrays
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

// to loop through the array
foreach($decoded['People'] as $key => $value) {

    echo 'Name: ' . $value['name'] . ' Age: ' . $value['age'] . '<br>';

}
?>
```

Comment: its abit late but i actually wanted to put everything in order. What you are doing is individually echo'ing the value, do you perhaps have solution to print the multiple of these in good order.

Comment: Currently i have this : if($resultSet->num_rows != 0){
// Turn the results into an Array
 while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
 {
   $id = $rows['id'];
   $customer = $rows['customer_ini'];   
   $printed = $rows['printed'];
   if ($printed == 1){
    $printed = "Ja";
   } else {
    $printed = "Nee";
   }
print json_encode($rows);

   echo "<p>Customer Details: $customer <br />Geprint: $printed <br /> <a href='delete.php?del=$id'>Delete</a> <a href='printed_table.php?del=$id' onclick='print_table(id);'>Print</a></p>";
 }

Comment: how can i show the lets say only the name, but of all the rows.

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. Again, really appreciated mate :)